# Need help to get unique data in Windows Powershell code

Tags: windows, powershell

There is a file named `data.xlsx`. Cells in `data.xlsx` consist of multiple lines and every line is a string.

Assuming strings in the same cell are unique, I want to get unique output from all cells in `data.xlsx`. However, the code below does not work:

```
powershell -Command "$data = @(); $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application; $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open('%excelFile%'); $sheet = $workbook.Sheets('Sheet1'); " ^
    "for ($col = %startColumn%; $col -le %endColumn%; $col++) { " ^
    "    for ($row = %startRow%; $row -le %endRow%; $row++) { " ^
    "        $cell = $sheet.Cells.Item($row, $col).Text; " ^
    "        $data += $cell; " ^
    "    } " ^
    "} $uniqueData = $data -split \"`r`n\" | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() } | Sort-Object -Unique; " ^
    " $uniqueData | Out-File -FilePath '%outputFile%' -Encoding UTF8; " ^
```

Furthermore, if I append the code below it will work:

```
"Get-Content '%outputFile%' | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() } | Sort-Object -Unique | Out-File -FilePath '%outputFile_f%' -Encoding UTF8"
```

I am confused about why the first code block does not work.

Comment: It sounds like your xlsx file is not actually an Excel workbook

Comment: This doesn't look right : $sheet.Cells.Item($row, $col).Text   What is ITEM?  A cell is not an item.  Remove ITEM.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheets.item and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells

Comment: remove Item does not work. Thank you.

Comment: Remove ```-split \"`r`n\"```, so you will have `$uniqueData = $data | ForEach-Object {...} `. Variable `$data` is already an array of strings you just need to trim and sort unique

Comment: Appreciate your effort. Split in the code is really not necessary. However, remove it still get wrong output.

Comment: Then show us the output you get and explain why that is not what you expect. Also show us output you DO want to get. P.S. please use `@username` in a comment if you want to reply to someone so he/she will get notified.

Comment: cell 1: "a""b""c". cell 2: "b""d". Then I get "a""b""c""b""d" which is not unique. I just want "a""b""c""d". I am new here. Thanks for your help. @Theo